# Localization Testing Tool For Localized Mobile Applications (Android , Iphone , WP)

Tags: testing, mobile, localization

Is there any Tool Available in the market to test the localized mobile apps under different locales. 
Like, the Typical Tests performed on localized mobile apps will be ..
1)Application functionality - For basic navigation
2)String Truncation Validation
3)Validate the translated Symbols and Images must be appropriate to the Target Language

and so on ..

Please provide me your valuable information on this ..
Really thankful to you..

Comment: And also please Share me , whether such tool can be possible because localized app testing will be difficult, so is there existing Tools like QTP, ROBOTIUM, SELENIUM, etc. can test the localized mobile apps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have some experience using [Robotium](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/) to automate the localization testing of our mobile applications.

The main thing you want to look for in any automation solution for localized applications on any platform, is the ability to uniquely identify each object you will need to interact with (buttons etc.), using an identifier that will not change on different locales. That way, your automation code will run on any locale (we would not want to have a different code base per locale).

In my experience, it's much quicker to develop a Robotium (Java based) solution for automated testing of Android applications (other solutions such as [SeeTest](http://experitest.com/) exist, but I have not found it great).

QTP I've found to be very useful for desktop applications, but not mobile. [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) is good for automating web applications, and you can use [Selenium Mobile](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverForMobileBrowsers) to interact with the browser on a mobile device if you need to.

I blogged recently detailing how we use Robotium to test our Android application, and my experiences using it, you can find this at the link below.

[Automate your Android App Testing Using Robotium](http://www.jimmycollins.org/blog/?p=633)

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. It is really helpful, other than Robotium we dont have any tool which work for Mobile Applications Testing ??
Actually i m looking for the Tools Test Cases, how they validates the app which is localized perfectly like what i mentioned three points at the Top.. Could u please go through on it and clarify my thought with any useful link. Im really appreciating your response here ..Thank u So Much..

Comment: I haven't looked in an algorithm for String Truncation Validation, but I know some exist (but are not open source unfortunetly).

Answer (score 1):

When testing your application on the devices and networks that it’s intended for, carrying out user acceptance testing in the target market could highlight any market-specific concerns and return some very useful market specific feedback. Consider a beta (test stage) program, customer early-adopter program or work with a company like ICanLocalize who use only translators that translate into their native tongue.

If, for example, your global mobile app implements its own pop-up touchscreen keyboard, you should consider the needs of your international users to ensure that they can enter text in their native script. While mobile devices and smart phones are being shipped with increasingly higher screen resolutions, usability and aesthetics need to be considered too. Translated text can often expand by as much as 25 percent, affecting the layout and visual appeal of your app. Some scripts may be very difficult to read if the displayed font size is not sufficiently large.
There are more things to consider when localizing an application and I’m not talking about plain old translation of code here. Any company hoping to win over an international audience can make this job significantly easier by planning ahead for the translation process:

Think carefully about words used to describe menus. 
Get a native-language linguist to test your application
Avoid colloquialisms
Consider navigation.

http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/2012/10/planning-ahead-for-translation-when-developing-a-mobile-app/